# What actually determines a 'borrow' in binary subtraction?

Tags: binary, binary-operations

Given `Byte1` and `Byte2` in binary. How to determine whether `Byte1 - Byte2` results in a borrow or not?

I've seen 10 different ways:

1. Iterate over the bits in `Byte1` and `Byte2` in parallel, if we ever
   come across a bit in `Byte2` that is greater than its equivalent bit
   in `Byte1`, we have a borrow.
2. If 'Byte1 < Byte2` we have a borrow

I'm asking because I'm writing a CHIP-8 interpreter. One of the opcodes is `8XY5: Register Y is subtracted from Register X. Register F is set to 0 when there's a borrow, and 1 when there isn't`

I've seen implementations that did the second approach:

```
if(Register[X] < Register[Y]) 
    Register[0xF] = 0; // there is a borrow
else 
    Register[0xF] = 1;                  
Register[X] -= Register[Y];
```

That doesn't really make sense to me. Take 5 and 3 in binary for example:

```
0101 -
0011
----
0010
```

According to their approach, there is no borrow, but we can clearly see that there's a borrow happening in the second bit (0 - 1)

I'm confused. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely confusing language.  What they intend to mean is whether there is *ultimately* a borrow from beyond the highest-order bit.  The point is to tell whether the difference of two positive numbers is negative, and then paired with the skip instruction you can do conditional jumps ("if x < y { ... }").  One way to think about it is extend the first number with an initial zero bit:

```
0|0011 -
 |0101
------
1|1110
```

That first 1 reflects the "borrow."

Comment: Kind of makes sense. Do you have a source for this information or you thought about it yourself?

So that means if I take the difference `D`, `D = Byte1 - Byte2` then take `S`, the sign of `D`, `S = (D << 7) & 0x1` If `S == 1` it means the sign is negative, thus `Byte1 < Byte2` so we have borrow. Correct? (Note I shifted to the left cause Chip-8 is Big Indian - correct me on this if I'm wrong)

Comment: Be careful, this isn't what big endian means.  Memory is a sequence of numbers 0-255, and big/little endian is saying in which order to store the base-256 representation of the number.  When doing bit-arithemtic in an ALU, the right-most bit is still the lowest place value.  Say you're in a system with 16-bit numbers.  If Byte1, Byte2 are unsigned 16-bit numbers, and D=Byte1-Byte2, then B=!((D>>8)&0x1) is whether there isn't a borrow.  You can't just look at the 8th bit (i.e., D>>7) because it's not whether the result is two's complement negative, but whether a borrow from the top happened.

Comment: Perhaps one thing to keep in mind for why this is useful: if you are subtracting a multiple-byte number from a multiple-byte number, you can use whether a borrow happened to keep borrowing from the next number, like in the grade-school subtraction algorithm.  (Also, if you're writing an interpreter, make sure you have test programs with known results; otherwise you have no idea whether you're implementing things correctly.)

Comment: This criteria doesnt work when Byte2 is zero. 1111 - 000 doesnt produce a borrow, but since 0 is bigger than -1, it would according to the criteria.

Comment: @WernerGermánBusch Which criteria are you referring to? Considering "The point is to tell whether the difference of two positive numbers is negative," 1111 is $15$ (not $-1$).